Two source commands in a shell file do not update arguments sent to source the second time
First file (trigger.sh):
#!/usr/bin/env bash


echo "Configuring tests"
echo "Source 1"
source ./run-1.sh -m "George"

echo "Source 2"
source ./run-1.sh -m "Fred"
echo "End"

Second file (run-1.sh):
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "IN run-1"
while getopts m: flag; do
  case "${flag}" in
  m) MODE=${OPTARG} ;;
  esac
done
echo "before mode"
echo "$MODE"
echo "after mode"

Output:
./trigger.sh
Configuring tests
Source 1
IN run-1
before mode
George
after mode
Source 2
IN run-1
before mode
George
after mode
End

If you look at the Output when trigger.sh is executed, you will see the second source call does not update the argument to "Fred" but it keeps it as "George".
What's the reason for this? Any workaround using source?

getopts sets state. If you want to reset that state, that's an explicit operation. Or just don't use getopts; there are perfectly good if not better argument parsing approaches that don't involve it at all (see BashFAQ #35's "Manual Loop" section)

(aside: if something is written to be sourced by bash, use .bash rather than .sh; if it's meant to be executed rather than sourced, don't use any extension at all; see commandname extensions considered harmful -- yes, it's hosted on a personal website, but it's been the canonical link on the topic for the bash IRC channel for well over a decade).

@CharlesDuffy Thanks for the comments. I ended up resetting state for getopts. I originally thought it might be an issue with source. But, I will look into feasibility of other args parsing approaches. Appreciate all the links you have provided.

Aside from the correct remark by Charles Duffy, I would reconsider the design of your scripts. Do you really have to make the interface to a script, which is supposed to be source, so complex that you need getopts for parsing them?
